# Mongo output to shell variable

Tags: linux, mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

Is it possible to store mongo output into a variable in shell script, below is the example query which prints decimal date

ex: 1489442900000

```
maxdate =$( echo mongo getmaxdate.js --quiet)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no space between the variable name and the command during the assignment.

```
variable_name=$(command1 |command2 .....)
```

In your case:

```
maxdate=$( mongo getmaxdate.js --quiet)
```

Make sure to preserve the formatting of the output. if `echo`'ed Without double quote the whole content will show up in one line.

```
echo "$maxdate"
```

Comment: actually it should be enclosed in backtick    "$(echo `mongo getmaxdate.js --quiet`)" , this is working for me.